# Number of seemingly brightest stars: minimum around G-stars

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, stars

This plot gives the amount of the seemingly 10000 brightest stars.

Can someone help me to explain why there's a minimum at number 3, I know how to explain 1 (there are less 
big stars) and 2 (small stars are not bright enough)

[image: amount of seemingly 100000 brightest stars]

Comment: Could you explain the plot a little more? What are the axes?

Comment: You should give a reference for the plot.

Comment: on the Y-axis is the number of stars, and on the X-axes is the type of the star (related to the mass) (it's a histogram)

Comment: 10000 brightest in terms of _absolute_ magnitude or _relative_ magnitude?

Comment: @probably_someone I'm sorry, but it's the relative magnitude...

Comment: @Mari3 Well, then, what I said still roughly applies, assuming that we live in a fairly typical stellar population. This is probably pretty close to true, since we live in a fairly typical region of the galaxy.

Comment: @probably_someone thank's a lot!

Comment: You'll find a good answer to an identical question here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/21296/can-someone-explain-this-diagram-showing-the-spectral-type-distribution-of-brigh

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this plot is a plot of the distribution of the 10,000 brightest stars in terms of *absolute magnitude* (i.e. the 10,000 stars with the highest luminosity), there's a simple explanation:

This plot isn't only talking about main-sequence stars. It includes things like red giants, which are very red but also *very* bright simply because they're **huge**. So you have two populations of bright stars: the very blue, very hot, very bright main-sequence stars in the O-A range, and the very red, not as hot, but also very bright red giants in the K-M range. If you look at a Hertzsprung-Russell diagram, you can see these two populations clearly. Drawing a horizontal line across this diagram at an absolute magnitude of roughly 0 will give you the distribution you see in that plot.

This also applies to the relative magnitude to some extent; the distribution is distorted by the fact that the brightness of each star is weighted with distance from us, but, since 10,000 is a lot of stars, if we live in a fairly typical stellar population (i.e. with roughly average relative numbers of dwarfs and giants), then it shouldn't distort the distribution into something unrecognizable. If we lived in the middle of an elliptical galaxy, full of old, red stars and devoid of star-forming regions that would produce the bright, shortlived O-A type stars, then yes, the distribution would look quite different. And if we were looking at the 10 brightest stars instead of the 10,000 brightest, then our distribution would very heavily depend on what kind of stars we happen to be next to. But for our purposes here, it seems that we live in a fairly typical region of a fairly typical spiral galaxy, so there shouldn't be too much difference in what you'd expect for the general distribution of the 10,000 brightest stars in terms of relative magnitude vs. the general distribution of the 10,000 brightest stars in terms of absolute magnitude.

[image]

Comment: This is definitely an exam/test question.

Comment: @RobJeffries Oops, yeah, you're probably right. What's the recommended procedure at this point?

Comment: Fortunately your answer is only partly correct, since this is not the most luminous stars, it is the brightest stars.

Comment: @RobJeffries That is true. Is there something incorrect about the paragraph in the answer addressing this?

Comment: @RobJeffries Hello, this is an example exam question, it's not a real exam question, sorry if I can't ask those things here... If you want me I can send you my exam planning, I haven't had exams yet so that's how you can make sure it was not for a 'real' exam question

Comment: @probably_someone  Hello, this is an example exam question, it's not a real exam question, sorry if I can't ask those things here... If you want me I can send you my exam planning, I haven't had exams yet so that's how you can make sure it was not for a 'real' exam question

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that most of the OBAF stars are large stars on the main sequence. G stars are mostly on the main sequence, but these are not bright enough to make a plot of the 1000 brightest stars. K stars are red giants. This is the position of the red clump.